# How do you create an async method?

Tags: c#, async-await

How do I make below simple method async so that i can it call it like `await DoSomething`

```
public void DoDomething()
{
    string d = "doing something";
}
```

Editing Question for what I am actually doing in my method

```
public void RunValidationScripts()
{
    string scriptDirPath = @"D:\ValidationScripts";
    string[] psScriptsPath = Directory.GetFiles(scriptDirPath);

    Dictionary<string, Collection<PSObject>> result = new Dictionary<string, Collection<PSObject>>();

    foreach (string scriptPath in psScriptsPath)
    {
        result.Add(scriptPath, ExecutePSScript(scriptPath));
    }
}
```

I am using package `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`

```
private Collection<PSObject> ExecutePSScript(string scriptFilePath)
{
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(scriptFilePath);

        var results = ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(scriptFilePath)).Invoke();

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Comment: There's nothing to make async in that code. Why do you want to call it using `await`? It matters. You may not have understood what `async/await` do. Or you may need to use code specific to your real problem. If you want to implement an asynchronous interface member you could just return a `Task`, you don't need to use `async/await`

Comment: If you really want to use `await` without actually doing anything asynchronously you could change the return type to just `Task` and add `return Task.CompletedTask;` at the end of a method. If you want to create a fire-and-forget task you can't just use `Task.Run()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, edited question. i wanted to make `RunValidationScripts` method async.

Comment: Are you saying you want to off-load the work its doing into a background thread?

Comment: yes @GoodNightNerdPride

Comment: @Pankaj *why*? That still doesn't explain anything. Do you want to avoid blocking a desktop application? Or speed up `Directory.GetFiles` ? Do you have a desktop or web application? Just sticking `async` won't fix anything. If you have a web app you gain nothing by using another thread to enumerate

Comment: @Pankaj `yes @GoodNightNerdPride` actually no. You still haven't explained what you want. PowerShell executes on a different process - so what is there to offload except `GetFiles` ? Don't you want to process those results anyway? It's `ExecutePSScript` that needs to be asynchronous and return a task. It won't do that with `Task.Run` because PowerShell is already asynchronous. All you need is to *await* each script to complete. You don't need a thread for that

Comment: You can use [Powershell.InvokeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invokeasync?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) instead of `Invoke` to execute scripts asynchronously and retrieve the results. After that you can insert them into the result List. There's no reason to use, and nothing to be gained from, `Task.Run`. If you use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` you won't have to wait for all files to be retrieved either

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, your comments are really helpful.

Comment: Post the actual code so people can write a proper answer then. What does `ExecutePSScript` do?

Comment: added @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Why do you *throw away* `Dictionary<string, Collection<PSObject>> result`? You can either return `result` or just execute scripts without storing their outcomes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is unclear. It looks like the actual problem is trying to execute PowerShell scripts asynchronously. Nothing will be gained by using Task.Run in this case. PowerShell scripts execute on a different thread already.

[Powershell.InvokeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invokeasync?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) can be used to execute a PowerShell script asynchronously. [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0) can be used to start enumerating files and processing them without waiting for all files to be retrieved.

Assuming the method executing the scripts looks something like this:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<PSObject>> ExecutePSScript(string scriptPath)
{
    var ps = PowerShell.Create();
    var content=await File.ReadAllTextAsync(scriptPath);
    ps.AddScript(content);
    var results=await ps.InvokeAsync();
    return results;
}
```

The calling method can be :

```
async Task RunValidationScriptsAsync(string folder)
{
    var allResults=new List<PSObject>();
    var files=Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder);
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        var results=await ExecutePSScript(file);
        allResults.AddRange(results);
    }
    //Do something with the results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a developer's perspective, there is one simple pratical rule of thumb that applies to most cases.

**Invoking asynchronous APIs**

The idea is that if you can choose between a synchronous and asynchronous API in the framework, you should opt for making all your code asynchronous and write your methods asynchronously, so that invocations to the aforementioned async framework methods is `await`ed.

If you don't utilize async methods, you should write synchronous methods as `async` does not provide any benefit

Answer (score -1):

Why would you make simple method async, If there is nothing to wait for (IO bound or CPU bound operation). But if there is really a need (fire and forget kind of situation), You could do,

```cs
public async Task DoDomething()
{
    string d=null;
    await Task.Run(()=> {
      d = "doing something";
    }
}
```

Having an async is not important if you dont want to wait here, so,

```cs
public Task DoDomething()
{
    string d=null;
    Task.Run(()=> {
      d = "doing something";
    }
}
```

will work too.

*Note: the question detail has changed significantly, and answer might not be relevant for this.*

Comment: Thanks @Code Name Jack. This is i wanted. It was just an example. I am doing lot more than assigning value to variable :-)

Comment: @Pankaj did you actually want to waste a thread doing nothing? You don't need `Task.Run` to just set a string. You could use `return Task.TaskCompleted;` instead.  That `Task.Run` will likely result in an `ObjectDisposedException` after a while too. What do you *really* want?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, edited question for what method i am trying to do ASYNC

Comment: @Pankaj you didn't. Just posted some code that does nothing asynchronous. Do you want to avoid blocking while enumerating files? Or speed up enumeration?